# Activating hover state over multiple elements using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to set up something that so when you hover over one element, another acts as if it too has been hovered over.

I've managed to get it working on first use but it seems to break it afterwards.

My Code:

```js
$(function() {
  $('#one').hover(function() {
    $('#three').css('box-shadow', '0 0 5px 2px black');
  }, function() {
    $('#three').css('box-shadow', 'none');
  });
});

$(function() {
  $('#three').hover(function() {
    $('#one').css('box-shadow', '0 0 5px 2px black');
  }, function() {
    $('one').css('box-shadow', 'none');
  });
});
```

```css
#one, #two, #three {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}
#one {
  background-color: orange;
}
#two {
  background-color: black;
  margin-left: 100px;
}
#three {
  background-color: blue;
  margin-left: 200px;
}
#one:hover, #two:hover, #three:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px 2px black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="one"></div>
<div id="two"></div>
<div id="three"></div>
```

Comment: I would suggest using class for changes over multiple childs. All the CSS is in CSS file then and the code works clearly

Comment: Why not just set up a class and add and remove it - would be a lot easier to maintain

Comment: It only breaks if you hover of the blue square. Don't use identifiers. Group your elements by giving them a common attribute, such as `data-group="x"` and use that as a selector. That way you don't have to worry about which identifier is also part of the group and use CSS classes, don't embed styles like that, it's harder to maintain and edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you had 2 mistakes:

1.you wrote 'one' instead of '#one'

2.the mouse out function only makes the other one to stop being hovered. (sorry for bad English)

This is the fixed(working) code

```js
$(function() {
  $('#one').hover(function() {
    $('#three').css('box-shadow', '0 0 5px 2px black');
    $('#one').css('box-shadow', '0 0 5px 2px black');
  }, function() {
    $('#three').css('box-shadow', 'none');
    $('#one').css('box-shadow', 'none');
  });
});

$(function() {
  $('#three').hover(function() {
    $('#one').css('box-shadow', '0 0 5px 2px black');
    $('#three').css('box-shadow', '0 0 5px 2px black');
  }, function() {
    $('#one').css('box-shadow', 'none');
    $('#three').css('box-shadow', 'none');
  });
});
```

```css
#one, #two, #three {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}
#one {
  background-color: orange;
}
#two {
  background-color: black;
  margin-left: 100px;
}
#three {
  background-color: blue;
  margin-left: 200px;
}
#one:hover, #two:hover, #three:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px 2px black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="one"></div>
<div id="two"></div>
<div id="three"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a few things I would do:

1. Use classes instead of ids
2. Bind your hover event to a class and make use of data attributes so you do not repeat code
3. Add and remove a class rather than the actual style

```js
$('.box').hover(function() {
  var $this = $(this);
  if ($this.attr('data-target')) { /* check if attr exists */
    $(`#${$this.data('target')}`).addClass('hover');
  }
},
function() {
  var $this = $(this);
  if ($this.attr('data-target')) { /* check if attr exists */
    $(`#${$this.data('target')}`).removeClass('hover');
  }
});
```

```css
.box {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  float:left;
}
#one {
  background-color: orange;
}
#two {
  background-color: black;
}
#three {
  background-color: blue;
}
.box:hover,
.hover {
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px 2px black; /* use a class that is the same as the actual hover, then you only need to edit in one place if you change it */
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box" id="one" data-target="three"></div>
<div class="box" id="two"></div>
<div class="box" id="three" data-target="one"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you are using `.css()` function, then you have to use `!important` in some of your `css` attributes like the following:

```
  $(function() {
  $('#one').hover(function() {
    $('#three').css('box-shadow', '0 0 5px 2px black');
  }, function() {
    $('#three').css('box-shadow', 'none');
  });
});

$(function() {
  $('#three').hover(function() {
    $('#one').css('box-shadow', '0 0 5px 2px black');
  }, function() {
    $('#one').css('box-shadow', 'none');
  });
});

#one, #two, #three {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}
#one {
  background-color: orange;
}
#two {
  background-color: black;
  margin-left: 100px;
}
#three {
  background-color: blue;
  margin-left: 200px;
}
#one:hover, #two:hover, #three:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px 2px black !important; /* here we use important*/
}
```

**[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/peg0a5Lj/)**

---

**But** it is recommended to do such thing with toggling a `class` like the following:

```
$(function() {
  $('#one').hover(function() {
    $('#three').addClass("act");
  }, function() {
    $('#three').removeClass("act");
  });

  $('#three').hover(function() {
    $('#one').addClass("act")
  }, function() {
    $('#one').removeClass("act");
  });
});

#one, #two, #three {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}
#one {
  background-color: orange;
}
#two {
  background-color: black;
  margin-left: 100px;
}
#three {
  background-color: blue;
  margin-left: 200px;
}
#one:hover, #two:hover, #three:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px 2px black;
}

.act
{
box-shadow: 0 0 5px 2px black;
}
```

**[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/foz17424/)**

---

**Don't forgot to change your last `(one)` to `(#"one")`** as others recommended before!

Answer (score 1):

You can use classes and add/remove classes on hover. You can also use groups to identify which elements you wish to "combine" using a data attribute for example.

```js
var $targets = $('[data-group=group1]');

$(function() {
  $targets.hover(function() {
    $targets.addClass('active');
  }, function() {
    $targets.removeClass('active');
  });
});
```

```css
div {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}

.first {
  background-color: orange;
}

.second {
  background-color: black;
  margin-left: 100px;
}

.last {
  background-color: blue;
  margin-left: 200px;
}

div:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px 2px black;
}

.active {
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px 2px black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div data-group="group1" class="first"></div>
<div class="second"></div>
<div data-group="group1" class="last"></div>
```

Your CSS doesn't need to target all identifiers separately. Just target them all at ones, either directly through their element`div:hover` or `div {}` or give them all the same class if you have more divs on your page.

In general I would not use identifiers in CSS as those target a single element, while classes can be assigned to multiple elements. Also, identifiers are often used/removed or changed by programmers, specially if the HTML is rendered through a dynamic process. Though CSS classes should be more reliable as coders shouldn't touch them as they are for style not functionality.